# How to Add LaunchScreen using Storyboard for iOS8 +

Tags: ios, xcode7, launch-screen

I am trying to add the Launchscreen using storyboard for all possible iOS devices and have following setting in place. 
I have Image set named Launch with images for iPad and iPhones.
[image]
Also, I have Added Launchscreen (Main.launchscreen) to the app in the following way:

[image]
[image]

I cannot see the Launchscreen being used for iPad's . Also I am not able to set the Launchscreen when the app opens in Landscape mode for both iPhone and iPads.

Kindly let me know what I may be missing ?

Comment: FYI - you don't use any launch images when setting up a launch screen.

Comment: I am not using the Launch Image. I ahve given LaunchScreen name as Main.storyboard.

Comment: I made that statement because your question states you created a Launch image asset and you added a screenshot of those launch images. So I pointed out that they are not used when setting up a launch screen. Only the Main storyboard will be used as your launch screen. But you provide absolutely no information about that storyboard so it will be very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: I agree I might have done something wrong. It will be great if you can help me. I can see the LaunchScreen displaying properly for iPhone5s but cannot see the same for the iPads. Also i have no Idea how Launchscreen renders in landscape mode.

Comment: Hi :) Let's try to solve problem. Do not comment without understanding what am i trying to achieve.
In the above screenshot, i am using the Main.storyboard as the Launchscreen and I am already able to use it in my iPhone 5. Probably you are getting confused as i have named it as Main.

I am trying to use Launchscreen storyboard (named as Main.storyboard) as the launchscreen file such that it displays when the app starts.